# Is there a way to get an event on clipboard update?

Tags: linux, sdl, clipboard, x11, sdl-2

I'm trying to get the clipboard in my program to be synchronized with the one SDL is interfacing with.
Fetching clipboard data constantly is not an option. I would like to only be notified when it changes.

I tried listening for SDL_CLIPBOARDUPDATE event but no matter what I do I'm unable to trigger the event.

Linux 5.2.6 | X 1.20 | SDL 2.0.10

Comment: There seems to be a combination of two factors - SDL https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/ff2e36039fd2/src/video/x11/SDL_x11events.c#l623 not raising an event on receiving clipboard and X11 not delivering clipbord data unless application explicitly requests it (and, as far as I understand, application "owning" selection must copy it itself when requested). It appears SDL internally polls for clipboard data on e.g. windows and wayland, but with X11 it may cause a stutter/delay waiting for clipboard data. So short answer is SDL wouldn't help you much with X11, I suppose.